# Dynamically add html content with binding in angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, web-applications, data-binding

I have an Input like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
```

and a list which is placed on the scope:

```
$scope.list = ["<span>{{name}}</span>","<span>{{name2}}</span>"]
```

I am trying to run over the list using ng-repeat and display all the list element and have a binding between the input and the span content.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item">
                    <span>{{$index + 1}}.</span>
                    <span ng-bind-html="to_trusted(item)"></span>
                </div>
```

Where:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
    }
```

What is the right way to do so?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem? I'm guessing you're seeing `{{name}}` instead of the value of `name`?

Comment: this should work as is, can you please setup a plunker

Comment: {{name}} is being displayed instead of the input value

Comment: Please have a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GqODeogbXemimTZ9nurY?p=preview

Comment: yeaa, you added plain html without applying directive that's why brackets

Comment: why you don't using [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can avoid to using `ng-bind-html`, you better use [ng-include](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) for templating,
here working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDRanLfuJglCQ2mRpw1r?p=preview).

 Like here:

#### html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" >
         ...//other things
        <span ng-include="'t1'"  ></span>
    </div>
```

#### template

```
<script id="t1" type="text/ng-template">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </script>
```

#### controller

```
$scope.list = [
      {name:"name1"},
      {name:"name2"},
      {name:"name3"}
      ];
```

Comment: It's the same as the one I posted yesterday

Comment: Thanks! But can I dynamically add a template? Cause I have a lot of templates and it will be a shame to load all of them while I will eventually need only one or two?

Comment: How come this Plunker doesn't work? http://plnkr.co/edit/GqODeogbXemimTZ9nurY?p=preview

Comment: if you need the dynamic template,y can do that using [compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/service/$compile),that the reason why your plunk is not working,i will set up plunk with example a little bit later